# Rainbow Trails Video Effect

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, video

This is an effect to augment juggling videos:

[image: output]

The goal of this effect is to add a rainbow trail to a video using a tracked set of points.

[Link to source video](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-0L_TAQp71TE31lQxFQi-z0zcW8GxthU)

[Link to source data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12UaOtej1Is1r60abc1DoilXFva80qa0f)

[Link to complete Python script](https://gist.github.com/smeschke/f19ebfd48581cf1f6b7f441cc93ea129)

[Link to complete video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xnA727D8Vc)

**This is how the script works step-by-step**:

Look at the relevant tracking points:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import math

# Read Source Data
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/stephen/Desktop/ss5_id_412.MP4')
df = pd.read_csv('/home/stephen/Desktop/ss5_id_412.csv')
#Write Video Out
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/stephen/Desktop/parabola.avi', fourcc, 120.0, (480,848))

# Define x and y as the first two columns of the spreadsheet
x = df['0']
y = df['1']
# Filter the data to smooth it out
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
x = savgol_filter(x, 7, 3)
y = savgol_filter(y, 7, 3)

# Start at frame number 0
frameNum = 0
# Define trail length
trail = 30
# Colors of the rainbow
rainbow = [(0,0,255), (0,127,255), (0,255,0), (255,0,0), (95,43,46), (255,0,139)]

def distance(a,b): return(math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2))
    
# Read a few frames of the video
# Define distance to calculate parabola from (in frames)
interval = 6
for i in range(interval):
    _,_ = cap.read()
    frameNum+= 1

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065080/draw-perpendicular-line-of-fixed-length-at-a-point-of-another-line
def perpendicular(slope, target, dist):
    dy = math.sqrt(3**2/(slope**2+1))*dist
    dx = -slope*dy
    left = target[0] - dx, target[1] - dy
    right = target[0] + dx, target[1] + dy
    return left, right

# Create a list to store past points
history = []
completeHistory = []

### This is the first loop through the video
### In this loop the rainbow-trail data is collected
while True:
    # Read Image
    _, img = cap.read()
    try: _ = img.shape
    except: break

    # Define a small distance
    smallDistance = 0.2

    # Find relevant data
    x_values = x[frameNum-interval:frameNum+interval]
    y_values = y[frameNum-interval:frameNum+interval]

    # Graph x and y values
    for point in zip(x_values, y_values):
        point = tuple(np.array(point,int))
        #cv2.circle(img, point, 1, (255,0,255), 2)
```

[image: tracking points]

Find a parabola that fits those points:

```
# Fit the parabola
coefs = poly.polyfit(x_values,y_values,2)
# Draw the parabola
target = int(x[frameNum]), int(poly.polyval(x[frameNum], coefs))
xRange = np.arange(target[0]-9,target[0]+9,1)
yRange = poly.polyval(xRange, coefs)
rangePoints = zip(xRange, yRange)
for ppp in rangePoints:
    center = tuple(np.array(ppp,int))
    #cv2.circle(img, center, 1, 123, 2)
#print(yRange)
```

[image: parabola gif]

Find the tangent of the parabola at the ball's position:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065080/draw-perpendicular-line-of-fixed-length-at-a-point-of-another-line
def perpendicular(slope, target, dist):
    dy = math.sqrt(3**2/(slope**2+1))*dist
    dx = -slope*dy
    left = target[0] - dx, target[1] - dy
    right = target[0] + dx, target[1] + dy
    return left, right

# Calculate the points on either end of the tangent line
leftX, rightX = x[frameNum] - smallDistance, x[frameNum] + smallDistance
left = leftX, poly.polyval(leftX, coefs)
right = rightX, poly.polyval(rightX, coefs)
# Calculate the slope of the tangent line
slope = (left[1]-right[1])/(left[0]-right[0])
intercept = target[1] - slope*target[0]
# Draw line
leftPoint = target[0]-10, (target[0]-10)*slope + intercept
rightPoint = target[0]+10, (target[0]+10)*slope + intercept
leftPoint = tuple(np.array(leftPoint, int))
rightPoint= tuple(np.array(rightPoint, int))
cv2.line(img, leftPoint, rightPoint, (123,234,123), 3)
```

[image: tangent line]

Draw the trails:

```
# List to save data for this frame
frameHistory = []

# Find Perpendicular points
for i in range(len(rainbow)):
    color = rainbow[i]
    left, right = perpendicular(slope, target, i-3)
    left, right = tuple(np.array(left, int)), tuple(np.array(right, int))
    point = left
    #cv2.circle(img, left, 1, color, 1)
    frameHistory.append(point)
history.append(frameHistory)
completeHistory.append(frameHistory)

# Show the history too
a,b,c,d,e,f = zip(*history)
for pointList, color in zip([a,b,c,d,e,f], rainbow):
    for i in range(len(pointList)-1):
        pass
        cv2.line(img, pointList[i], pointList[i+1], color, 2)

# Pop the oldest frame off the history if the history is longer than 0.25 seconds
if len(history)>15:
    history.pop(0)
```

[image: not smoothed]

Smooth the trails (this is the final output):

```
#Smooth the data
smoothed = []
a,b,c,d,e,f = zip(*completeHistory)
for i in a,b,c,d,e,f:
    x, y = zip(*i)
    x = savgol_filter(x, 27, 3)
    y = savgol_filter(y, 21, 2)
    smoothed.append(list(zip(x,y)))


# Read Source Data
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/stephen/Desktop/ss5_id_412.MP4')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/stephen/Desktop/parabola.avi', fourcc, 120.0, (480,848))
frameNum = 0
### This is the second loop through the video
### In this loop the smoothed rinbow-trail points are diplayed
while True:
    # Read Image
    _, img = cap.read()
    if frameNum>21:
        for color, line in zip(rainbow, smoothed):
            pointList = line[frameNum-20:frameNum-5]
            for i in range(len(pointList)-1):
                a,b = tuple(np.array(pointList[i], int)), tuple(np.array(pointList[i+1], int))
                cv2.line(img, a,b, color, 2)
```

[image: smoothed gif slow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is SO COOL. Some minor improvements:

`from scipy.signal import savgol_filter` should be moved to the top of the file

You should be moving your global code into subroutines.

`distance` can be replaced with the built-in `np.linalg.norm`.

`_,_ = cap.read()` does not need any return assignments; just call `cap.read()`.

```
    left = target[0] - dx, target[1] - dy
    right = target[0] + dx, target[1] + dy
```

would benefit from unpacking:

```
x, y = target
left = x - dx, y - dy
right = x + dx, y + dy
```

By PEP8, `frameHistory` would be `frame_history`, and `pointList` to `point_list`.

You have a bunch of hard-coded paths - these should be parametrized, either to global constants, or a configuration file etc.